# Django form performance

Tags: mysql, django

I asked this in Code Review but it was rejected with a cause of "broken code."   That is why I'm asking it here. This site is probably more appropriate for this question than the Code Review one.

In my app, a user can modify a course that they created.   One field is a "teacher" field and the user can select a different person to be the teacher.   This ForeignKey creates 138 duplicated queries and I can't figure out how to make it more efficient.

Model:

```
class CourseCatalog(models.Model):
course_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Course name", max_length=50)
course_desc = models.TextField(verbose_name="Course Description")
teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, blank=True, null=True,
verbose_name='Course Owner', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
...
```

View:

```
class EditCourseCatalog(UpdateView):
model = CourseCatalog
fields = ['course_name','course_desc', 'teacher']
template_name = 'school/course_catalog/new_edit_form.html'
```

Template:

```
...
<h3>Course Form</h3>
{{ user.teacher }}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{{form|crispy}}
...
```

Here is the query from debug that is duplicated 138 times. The only difference between the queries is the `school_familymember`.`id` = 220.

```
SELECT `school_familymember`.`id`, `school_familymember`.`password`,
```

`school_familymember`.`last_login`, `school_familymember`.`is_superuser`,
`school_familymember`.`username`, `school_familymember`.`first_name`,
`school_familymember`.`last_name`, `school_familymember`.`email`.`school_familymember`.`is_staff`, `school_familymember`.`is_active`, `school_familymember`.`date_joined`, `school_familymember`.`family_id`, `school_familymember`.`middle_name`, `school_familymember`.`family_member_role_id`, `school_familymember`.`address1`, `school_familymember`.`address2`, `school_familymember`.`city`, `school_familymember`.`state`, `school_familymember`.`zip_code`, `school_familymember`.`notes`, `school_familymember`.`gender`, `school_familymember`.`phone_number`, `school_familymember`.`cell_phone_number` FROM `school_familymember` WHERE `school_familymember`.`id` = 220

The Teacher model is also a foreign key to the FamilyMember table and this is where I think I'm having the issue.   I'm wondering if there is a way to make one single query to collect the family names and ids and then use that for the drop down list in the form.  Can I do this with the built in form managers or do I have to scrap that and create the queries in the view and pass them to the form?

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    family_member = models.OneToOneField(FamilyMember, verbose_name='name')
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Comment: Is that the complete `Teacher` model? This is typical behaviour if `Teacher.__unicode__` or `Teacher.__str__` uses attributes from `self.family_member`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom model form, and in the `__init__` method change the teachers queryset to use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to be more efficient.

```
class CourseCatalogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['course_name','course_desc', 'teacher']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CourseCatalogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['teacher'].queryset = self.fields['teacher'].queryset.select_related('family_member')
```

Then use your new model form class in your view instead of specifying `fields`.

```
class EditCourseCatalog(UpdateView):
    model = CourseCatalog
    template_name = 'school/course_catalog/new_edit_form.html'
    form_class = CourseCatalogForm
```